# Printers start printing white pages for print jobs on Citrix

Tags: windows, printing, citrix

We use an application installed on a Windows 2003 server through Citrix Metaframe. Since Friday 17 march, most printers on the clients start printing white on white all distant print jobs.

We are using native printer drivers, not EasyPrint.

Restarting the server does not have any effect.

What could be the culprit ?

EDIT: The problem seems to be related with Windows Update [KB4013429 (OS Build 14393.953)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013429/windows-10-update-kb4013429). When I uninstall this update on the client computers, the printing resumes. My fear is that this update will reinstall with the next installation of updates. There is also [a tool to hide updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3183922/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-windows-update-from-reinstalling-in-windows-10), but this update is not hideable with this tool.

How could I solve this dilemma ?

Comment: Mapped printer ? and does you have rule to modify the printer driver on the metaframe farm ?

Comment: The same printer driver is installed on the server and the client. There was no problem for years now, and this is happening suddenly, without any change to the server configuration.

Comment: Test a print page then from notepad or another builtin app, in case its the published app that got a trouble

Comment: @yagmoth555 Thank you. This was the first time i got a timely answer on serverfault. I suspect a recent Windows update for Windows 10 on the clients. I have still to confirm.

Comment: If it's a update, then it mean the driver version no longer match, please validate that too :)

Comment: It is not a driver update, just a regular Windows update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use a no longer supported product you don't have many possibility to resolve that dilemma. (metaframe and windows server 2003.)

- Temporary fix your users problem by uninstalling that update except on one computer.
- Isolate a computer with that update to make the testing on it.
- For your test :

  - Be sure all update are done on your metaframe server (citrix update)
  - Be sure the 2003 is uptodate.
  - Install the latest Citrix Receiver (4.x) on the test computer as they support old citrix farm anyway.
  - If the receiver don't work, try the 3.4 enterprise receiver (still available), that receiver was a in between the online plugin and the Receiver 4.x.
  - If the test does not work, use Citrix Quick Launch, and generate a .ICA's file, from that file you will be able to test your farm if the receiver refuse to see your farm.
  - With the ICA you can directly connect to the published application, thus the concept of program neighborhood is bypassed in your case.
  - If nothing print, at that point create a new print queue on your computer and use a native printer driver like HP LaserJet 4, and put the IP of a real printer. (can be any printer brand, as that pcl format will be recognized by all brand)
  - Connect and try a printout this time.
  - If it work, change your printer driver to have one that work in another mode. For information, as we speak today each new print driver are all in [V4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/print/v4-printer-driver), but like the [V3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn705223) it's depreciated. I have no idea on the Windows 2003 what it can be.
  - If you can't change the printer driver on the windows 10's computer, then in your metaframe's console please make a policy that when that printer got mapped you use your server driver Y. Citrix got one native too.

That KB bring security fix to kernel mode driver, as such it maybe impact your printer mapping, and if you use a older Online plugin or Receiver it can be impacted too.

Comment: Thanks for your very thorough answer. I will get your suggestions a try and I'm sure they will get me further. Even much further than I expected to.